# Gcp Cloud Function deployment from local fails on Step #4 Builder Error ID: 46077d62

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

From the directory containing pom.xml, I ran the below deployment command and it failed in Step #4 Builder with below error message.

On my command line, this is the error i get

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build
> failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=gcp-ushi-merch-boomerang&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3D554f1f53-2434-4af8-948e-9479d7eedaa6%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fgcp-ushi-merch-boomerang%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild;
> Error ID: 46077d62

Can somebody what is the issue here?

**Deployment Command**

```
gcloud functions deploy my-cloud-function --entry-point com.company.cloudfunction.GCSTrigger --runtime java11 --trigger-resource test-bucket --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize --service-account=cf-continuous-deployment-sa@gcp-xxx-yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

**ERROR**

```
{
     insertId: "5a749b9b-ada9-4807-aeb3-d2747c5d3329-174"  
     labels: {
      build_step: "Step #4 - "builder""   
     }
     logName: "projects/gcp-ushi-merch-test/logs/cloudbuild"  
     receiveTimestamp: "2020-09-10T11:34:49.319956820Z"  
     resource: {
      labels: {
       build_id: "5a749b9b-ada9-4807-aeb3-d2747c5d3329"    
       build_trigger_id: ""    
       project_id: "gcp-ushi-merch-test"    
      }
      type: "build"   
     }
     severity: "INFO"  
     textPayload: "Step #4 - "builder": [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build: exit status 1"  
     timestamp: "2020-09-10T11:34:48.803279507Z"  
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your function code?

Answer (score 0):

From the folder we deploy, it's expected to have only **src** and **pom.xml**. If you have other files/folders it's recommended to mention them in **.gcloudignore** file.

In my case I had another test folder at the same level of src, which had the sub folder structure java/packageName/ClassName.java. In this case build fails.

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't mention about it as good practices to follow and the error message in logs too doesn't mention anything about it. Just an Error Id isn't of any use.